Getting error Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException wile try to generate the token for Microsoft Graph
Hi Team,
I am getting below error while trying to generate the token by using below code
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: 'AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Trace ID: 43e876a2-7f8d-4631-9b4d-8c8c875c8900 Correlation ID: ab584317-4e37-41ce-96c1-8610f6bd5293 Timestamp: 2024-05-08 09:40:05Z'
try
{
result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(
scopes: scopes,
username: this._loginId,
password: this._loginPassword
).ExecuteAsync();
}
Screen shot of error:
enter image description here
What I am trying to do?
I am Trying to get the token by using the User Id and Password , with that token we will use to invoke the Graph object
baseUri=https://graph.microsoft.com/betayour text
enter image description here

You cannot generate token username password flow if MFA is enabled for the user. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc Alternatively, make use of interactive flow to generate the access token.

As mentioned in this MS Document,

If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to the application, they will be blocked instead while generating token with username password flow.

Initially. I too got same error when I tried to generate token using username password flow for user having MFA enabled:

To resolve the error, switch to interactive flows for generating access token that involves user to login at least once for completing MFA.
Make sure to add redirect URI as http://localhost as redirect URI in Mobile & Desktop applications platform while using interactive flow:

When I ran below code to generate token with interactive flow, it asked me to login with MFA and got the response with list of team apps successfully as below:
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Text.Json;

class Program
{
    private static string clientId = "appId";
    private static string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    private static string redirectUri = "http://localhost";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "tenantId")
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .Build();

        try
        {
            // Interactive authentication flow
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync();
            string accessToken = result.AccessToken;

            // Make HTTP request to Microsoft Graph API
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Response:\n");

                    // Parse and format JSON response
                    var appsResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TeamsAppsResponse>(content);
                    foreach (var appInfo in appsResponse.value)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"App ID: {appInfo.id}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {appInfo.displayName}");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to call Microsoft Graph API. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MsalServiceException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

// Define classes to represent JSON response
public class TeamsAppsResponse
{
    public List<TeamsApp> value { get; set; }
}

public class TeamsApp
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}

Login Screen with MFA:

After successful authentication, I got the response with list of team applications in app catalogs as below:

In your case, change your authentication flow from username password flow to interactive flows that involves user to login at least once to complete MFA for generating token.
